# Highcharts tooltip not showing on unsort data

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I have a unsort data (on x-axis) and using Highcharts to display the graph. I knew the x-axis must sort to show the tooltip as the Highcharts document wrote. But my data could not be sorted by some reasons, so could anyone meet this problem before, please give any idea/solution to show the tooltip without sort x-axis data. If I sort, my data will be wrong.

My js:

```
var data = [
    [5.875, -20],
    [8.1875, -30],
    [8.875, -40],
    [9.5, -50],
    [10.125, -60],
    [10.5, -70],
    [10.875, -80],
    [11.375, -90],
    [11.6875, -100],
    [11.875, -110],
    [12.0625, -120],
    [12.625, -130],
    [12.4375, -140],
    [12.625, -150],
    [12.5, -160],
    [12.4375, -170],
    [12.4375, -180],
    [12.375, -190],
    [12.25, -200],
    [12.1875, -210],
    [11.9375, -220],
    [11.625, -230],
    [11.5, -240],
    [11.125, -250],
    [10.75, -260],
    [10.625, -270]
];

$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```

Or please check here http://jsfiddle.net/vuong/jedLowyv/4/

Thank you so much and have a nice day.

Comment: I can see the tooltips on your fiddle (when pointing to individual plot points); is it something different from these tooltips that you are talking about?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right. But when you put the mouse cursor over the graph, in some points the mouse-over is shown and in others not. In some points the mouse-over jumps to places other than where the pointer is. That is the problem i would like to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- sort your data: http://jsfiddle.net/jedLowyv/5/
- use scatter series with `lineWidth`: http://jsfiddle.net/jedLowyv/6/ (not: tooltip will show up only when hover one of markers directly)

Comment: Thank you! The second solution helps me for this. Can we disable marker but the tooltip still working? Thanks for your idea.
http://jsfiddle.net/vuong/jedLowyv/7/

Comment: No, you can't. Tooltip will show up only when hovering marker. However, you can set transparent color for it: http://jsfiddle.net/jedLowyv/9/